# Por qué una variable de tipo export no es modificada en un script ejecutado con exec

Tags: bash, script

[image: Ejemplo del bash con el export en el main y un run-script que lo modifica]

Por qué al ejecutar el run-script con exec,  no me esta modificando el valor de la variable tipo export, declarada en el main

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, No has dado una explicación exacta de tu situación o problema, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], He visto que has agregado Imágenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y facilites el uso del mismo, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: usa codigo como texto no en imagenes por favor.

Comment: Para quien tenga ganas de pasar el código del screenshot, no lo hagas. Es mejor que el que pregunta lo haga por su cuenta y se familiarice con las divertidas herramientas de edición :) Por cierto, @Carlos, bienvenido y buena pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Respuesta rápida: para que se cambie el valor de la variable del script necesitas cargar ese script ya sea con *source* o con *.*, (es un punto):

```
variable="valor 1"
. run-script.sh

echo "$variable"
```

### Respuesta larga

Lo que hacen los paréntesis es abrir una subshell casi aislada que no puede afectar el *namespace* del proceso padre (de main.sh).

Llo que hace `exec` es que lo que siga reemplazará a la shell.

Entonces, cuando haces un: `(exec ./run-script.sh)` tan sólo es ejecutar ese archivo que en realidad no tiene nada para ejecutar. Y si tuviera algo, como está dentro de una subshell, no tendrá efecto en el proceso padre, por lo que "variable" siempre tendrá el mismo valor declarado en "main.sh".